# How can I implement e-commerce datalayer on success page?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, google-api

I have installed Google Tag Manager and want to add an additional datalayer for ecommerce tracking on success page which contains the transition id, product specific data like sku, price, name, quantity and so on.

I want something like this for my success page after open body tag (pseudocode):

```
<body>
<script>
   <?php 
       if ( $this->getOrderId() ) $transactionId = $this->getOrderId();
       $currentOrder = Mage::getResourceModel( 'sales/order_collection' )->byId( $transactionId ); 
       $transactionAffiliation = Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName();
       $transactionTotal = $currentOrder->getTotal();
       $transactionTax = $currentOrder->getTax();
       $transactionShipping = $currentOrder->getShipping();
       $transactionProducts = $currentOrder->getProducts();
   ?>
   dataLayer = [{
     'transactionId': <?php echo "'".$transactionId."'" ?>,
     'transactionAffiliation': <?php echo "'".$transactionAffiliation."'" ?>,
     'transactionTotal': <?php echo $transactionTotal ?>,
     'transactionTax': <?php echo $transactionTax ?>,
     'transactionShipping': <?php echo $transactionShipping ?>,
     'transactionProducts': [
      <?php foreach( $transactionProducts as $product ): ?>
         {
         'sku': <?php echo "'".$product->getSku()."'" ?>,
         'name': <?php echo "'".$product->getName()."'" ?>,
         'category': <?php echo "'".$product->getCategory()."'" ?>,
         'price': <?php echo $product->getPrice() ?>,
         'quantity': <?php echo $product->getQuantity() ?>
         },
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      ]
  }];
</script>
...
```

So I have to replace this pseudocode with "real" Magento code to get the order details on succes page. But which correct functions should I use to implement this?

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: have use any extension?

Comment: I am just using this extension for integration of Google Tag Manager: http://de.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-tag-manager.html

Comment: Although an accepted answer, i'd like to put forth this extension for GTM, which I use in many projects. https://github.com/CVM/Magento_GoogleTagManager - it already has all the functionality to inject a datalayer. Additionally the developer added an event allowing the datalayer to be manipulated before it is rendered. An example of usage can be seen here: http://www.proxiblue.com.au/blog/exact-target-conversion-tracking-with-gtm/ - the blog post shows with code examples how to inject own variable using event to datalayer. is a lot neater, and does not require adding logic into .phtml pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code which can go on success page -:

```
<?php 
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$orderCurrency      = $order->getBaseCurrencyCode();
$orderGrandTotal    = $order->getBaseGrandTotal();
$orderShippingTotal = $order->getBaseShippingAmount();
$orderTax           = $order->getBaseTaxAmount();
$orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
//exit;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    <?php $intCtr=0;?>
    dataLayer.push({
      'ecommerce': {
        'purchase': {
          'actionField': {
            'id': '<?php echo $order->getIncrementId()?>',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
            'affiliation': '<?php echo $order->getAffiliation() ?>',
            'revenue': '<?php echo $orderGrandTotal?>',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
            'tax': '<?php echo $orderTax?>',
            'shipping': '<?php echo $orderShippingTotal?>',
            'coupon': '<?php echo $order->getCouponCode() ?>'
          },
          'products': [
          <?php foreach($orderItems as $item): ?>
                <?php $intCtr++;?>
                <?php if($item->getParentItemId()) continue;?>
          {                            
            'name': '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName()) ?>',     // Name or ID is required.
            'id': '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku()) ?>',
            'price': '<?php echo $item->getBasePrice()?>',
            'quantity': <?php echo $item->getQtyOrdered()?>
            <?php if ($intCtr==count($orderItems)):?>
}]
            <?php else:?>
},
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        }
      }
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

If you are not a Magento developer then recommendation is to use good module or extension which gives you much more insight and data to see better reporting in Google Analytics. Have a look at the following module

https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/enhanced-ecommerce-tracking-with-google-tag-manager.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why do I feel that theres a missing peice that has to be setup in gtm?  Do we need to add a tag with a transaction track type or anything?

Comment: @CDBrian - You just need to have Universal Analytics PageView Tag with just Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features and  use data layer on

Answer (score 1):

We created a free module that pushes DataLayer events for all of these [Enhanced eCommerce features](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce).

https://github.com/bubbleupdev/BubbleUp_Gtmdatalayer

`Creare_SEO` will let you put in the GTM container ID in the config, and render that snippet for you. It's also free.

https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO

If you don't feel like adding an extra module, you can add the GTM container code to your pages by adding it to the Miscellaneous Scripts config field at `System > Configuration > General > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts`